# Cox PH model and time splitting

Tags: cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I have question about the 'setup' for the data for Cox PH survival modelling in case of modelling time to 'breakdown'.

My data are houses and roof repair. For each house I have either the age of the house when it was repaired (Event_01=1) or, if was not repaired, the age at the time of sampling (Event_01=0). So I have the time to event (Event_Year) and the event itself (Event_01).

Furthermore I have some variables for use as explanatory variables like roof type, house price, square meters etc.

In most examples I have seen the age is the age of the 'object' (a person for instance) at the time of the treatment or whatever it is that is examined. However here the 'treatment' is building the house so the (start-)age is always 0 since the time starts when the house is brand new. But the age of the house is an important parameter when it comes the predicting the risk of repair - I would expect the risk to increase as the house age increases. What do you do in this case?

What I did was making time splits for several times like 5, 10, 15 etc. years. Like this:

Original data:

```
    House ID Event_Year Event_01
           1          3        0
           2          7        1
           3         11        0
           4         13        1
```

With splits at 5 and 10 years it becomes:

```
    House ID Split_Time Event_Year Event_01
           1          0          3        0
           2          0          5        0
           2          5          2        1
           3          0          5        0
           3          5          5        0
           3         10          1        0
           4          0          5        0
           4          5          5        0
           4         10          3        1
```

This way my model showed that the higher the split-year, the higher the hazard which matched my expectations.

So my question(s) is: Is this a good way to do it - did I misunderstand something completely? Is there a more simple way to include the house age in this case? Did I violate all assumptions about independence so it is useless?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need to do this.  You can do a survival analysis on the original data, you just don't have a "treatment".  Your only independent variable is "age of house".  Some of your cases are censored (that is, no event occurred) but that's fine - that is the issue that survival analysis was designed for.

Comment: That was what I did first but coxph return with a warning and the coefficient looked very strange,

It might be because the house age is actually the same as the event_Year and this is the dependent variable. As I see it the observation of all houses starts at house age = 0 and the event (or censoring) happens at the age of the house (and therefore it is the dependent variable). Hence in the original data all independent house ages are 0. So I have to make my own artificial house age input values by splitting in order to get house ages that are different from 0.

Comment: Categorizing your variable won't help.  The problem is Cox PH.  That requires an independent variable and you haven't got one.  In SAS, you can do what you want with PROC LIFETEST. See, in particular, [Example 3](http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=statcdc&cdcVersion=14.2&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_lifetest_examples03.htm&locale=en)

Comment: I don't see it as categorizing the dependent variable, I see it as creating an input house age variable that has values apart from 0. I don't change the dependent house age (=Event_Year) except concerning the time spit, but it still remains continuous. But I define points in time from where I observe the outcome. This way I will also be able to use the formula in scoring houses that are older than 0 years afterwards.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your example right way, I will have a look at it tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: I looked at the example and it looks to me like classical treatment data where the objects (persons) have an age when they enter the treatment. In my data the 'survival' time is always measured from when the house was built (age=0 years). So I still don't see any other way than what I wrote in the beginning - creating my own observation points in time. This way I can use the house age 'factor' as input (this is not the same as the Event time house age) and I can use the estimated formula for scoring houses that have an age that is different from 0. I can also make the house age numerical input